# HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. Oracle DB behind a VPN connection

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, openvpn

I have a oracle DB instance that is running behind a VPN. Upon establishing the VPN connection I am able to ping the host and port of the Database. However when I run `mvn spring-boot:run` it gives me the following error

```
2023-03-21 13:44:15.150 DEBUG 15189 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12899: value too large for column "AUD"."USER_LOG"."HOST" (actual: 31, maximum: 30)
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

refer to the attached image for more details
[image]

let me know what I am missing here. I was able to connect to the same DB previously from the same system. Recently I have updated the java version, downgrading the java version is not helping. I have updated the OpenVPN client, but since I am able to telnet and ping the server after establishing the VPN connection I believe VPN client is also not the cultprit

JDK-openjdk@19
os- macos 13.2.1
build-maven

Comment: consult your DBA.

Comment: Judging from the error something is being logged in the database upon login. For one thing the hostname, which appears to be longer then 30 chars and cannot be inserted in the audit table. This either needs to be fixed on the VPN level or the database level (or if the name includes part from your local machine, rename your local machine).

Comment: @M.Deinum please provide your comment as an answer. Changing the local machine name solved the issue. Althought its strange but glad it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error, something is being logged in an audit table upon doing a logon to the database. Looking at the error it tries to write a hostname into a table and the hostname column is only 30 chars long, while the (generated?) hostname is 31 chars long.

You have some solutions

1. Increase the column size in the audit table (probably outside your influence)
2. Could be a VPN thing with generating hostnames (probably outside your influence)
3. Change your computer-name to be 1 character shorter (not sure if that is already 31, or option 2 comes into play) so that it can be stored.